# How to build to another folder using angularCLI

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I have an anguar2 project inside of an ASP.NET Core application on Mac using Visual studio code. How do I have it build to a different folder for example:

```
ng build -output="../aspnetcoreapp/wwwroot/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CLI this way: `ng build --output-path ../aspnetcoreapp/wwwroot/`

There is a complete list of all available commands accessible via: `ng help`